# How to include an other contract from a different folder while unit-testing with truffle?

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-contract, unittesting

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Examples
  |
  +- Multiply
  |        +- Solidity
  |                 +- contracts
  |                           +- MultiplyContract.sol
  |
  +- UUIDProvider
               +- Solidity
                        +- contracts
                                  +- UUIDProviderContract.sol
```

And I want to test the (main) contract : **MultiplyContract.sol**

The **migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js** file looks like this:

```
var UUIDProviderContract = artifacts.require("../../UUIDProvider/Solidity/contracts/UUIDProviderContract.sol");
var MultiplyContract = artifacts.require("MultiplyContract");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(UUIDProviderContract);

    var multiplier = 4;
    deployer.deploy(MultiplyContract, multiplier);
};
```

However when running **truffle test**, I get this error:

```
Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\MultiplyContract.sol...
Compiling .\test\TestMultiplyContract.sol...
Compiling truffle/Assert.sol...
Compiling truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol...
C:\SmartContracts\Examples\Multiply\Solidity\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:63556
  throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources");
```

So how to include the **UUIDProviderContract.sol** ?

Or is this not possible and should I copy this to the same location as **MultiplyContract.sol**?

Answer (score 2):

Truffle looks for contract folder and compile all the contracts under it and sub folders.

`artifacts.require();`

should refer to compiled Contract not the sol file.